# When I try to use async keyword with firebase function, I got an error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I declared function like below:

```
exports.updateFriends = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {...
```

But I got an error like:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions currently runs on node 6, which doesn't support async/await syntax in ECMAScript 2017.  You will have to either write your JavaScript to use promises directly, or you can write your code in TypeScript, which can transpile async/await down to ECMAScript 2015, which is supported by node 6.  You can set up your project to use TypeScript using the Firebase CLI [as described in the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript)

Comment: Awesome! You are right. Now I've switched my language to TypeScript and no error. Thanks.

Comment: Great!  Please mark this answer as correct if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Update to this. You don't have to use TypeScript if you don't want to. You can just add `"engines": {"node": "8"}` to the `package.json` file in the firebase function directory and async/wait will work just fine.

Firebase cloud functions uses node6 by default but has node 8 available!